# javascript closure, not working?

Tags: javascript, telerik, closures

I have a function that I call to retrieve a sliding pane (telerik splitter control)
I thought I could use this function

```
function getZone() {
        var slidingZone = $find("<%= slidingZone.ClientID %>");
        return function () { return slidingZone; };
    }
```

so that it didn't have to "find" the sliding zone every time.  But it doesn't work.

This does...

```
function getZone() {
        var slidingZone = $find("<%= slidingZone.ClientID %>");
        return slidingZone;    
}
```

Can you tell me why the first one isn't working?

BTW, I'm using it like this....

```
function hideTreePane() {
        var paneId = "<%= slidingPane.ClientID %>";
        getZone().undockPane(paneId);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first function, returns a function, and you want the inner function to be executed.

If you invoke the result of it you will see it work, e.g.:

```
getZone()();
```

I think you want the following, use an immediately executed anonymous function, to call the `$find` method only once, storing its result:

```
var getZone = (function() {
  var slidingZone = $find("<%= slidingZone.ClientID %>");
  return function () { return slidingZone; };
})();
```

Comment: @Tom, yes, because IMO there's no point to do what the accepted answer suggests, the returned function is not really useful, you'll still execute `$find` *always*, behind the scenes... And it can cause confusion e.g., How a developer would know that `getZone` actually returns another function to be executed?

Comment: why would it execute find behind the scenes?  My impression was the returned function would have access to the result of $find (the variable slidingZone) due to javascript's implementation of closure.  That was kind of what I was going for.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to call the function you are returning from getZone:

```
getZone()().undockPane( paneId );
```

It wasn't working because the function `getZone` itself does not have a member called `undockPane`.

**EDIT:**

I think it would be better to do this:

```
function getZone() {
    if ( getZone.cache === undefined )
        getZone.cach = $find("<%= slidingZone.ClientID %>");
    return getZone.cache;
}
```

Then you would call like this:

```
getZone().undockPane( paneId );
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your returning a function and you need to evaluate it...
If using the first function this may work..

```
function hideTreePane() { 
    var paneId = "<%= slidingPane.ClientID %>"; 
    var zoneFunc = getZone();
    zoneFunc().undockPane(paneId); 
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first example you're returning a function, therefore `getZone()` becomes a function itself and you need to do `getZone()()` to get the `slidingZone` value you want.

There's no need to wrap your return value in a function for this case.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a function from the first example, not a value.  You'd need to evaluate the function for it to work.  Try something like.

```
var slidingZone;
function getZone() {
    if (!slidingZone) {
        slidingZone = $find( ... );
    }
    return slidingZone;
}
```

It would be better for this to be part of a "class" so that the caching variable isn't in the global scope.